# How can I pass a VBScript string to be the default value in my HTML input box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vbscript

I am making an HTA wizard using HTML and VB.

This is some VB code that I was given. I need to take the value that SN2 is set to in this and make it appear as the default text in my html code as the computer name.

I'm not sure how to call the VB code to display into my wizard's Computer Name textbox. Is this possible to do?

**VB Code**

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colBIOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
For each objBIOS in colBIOS
            MF=objBIOS.Manufacturer
            SN=objBIOS.SerialNumber
Next
intCharacters = 7
SN2 = RIGHT(SN, intCharacters)
            WScript.Echo SN2
            WScript.Echo MF
```

I tried the above, but I also tried taking all of that, and making a Sub out of it, like so:

```
Sub SN2
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colBIOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
    For each objBIOS in colBIOS
                MF=objBIOS.Manufacturer
                SN=objBIOS.SerialNumber
    Next
    intCharacters = 7
    SN2 = RIGHT(SN, intCharacters)
                ‘WScript.Echo SN2
                'WScript.Echo MF
End Sub
```

And then I tried to call it in my HTML code by setting value=SN2, using both the above methods. But obviously that just makes the HTML text box show "SN2" every time:

```
<table cellpadding="0" border=0 style="position:relative; left:1%">
    <tr valign=bottom style="text-align:right">
        <td class="hideextra">
            <img src="comp.png"></img>
            <b>New Computer Details</b>
        </td>
</table><br>
<table cellpadding="0" border=0>
    <tr valign=middle style="text-align:left">
        <td>
            <b>Computer Name</b><br><br>        
        </td>
        <th style="text-align:left">
            <input type=text id="ComputerName" name=ComputerName value=SN2 /><br><br>
            </select>
        </th>
</table>
```

I was trying to research a way to set the value to a string set in the VB portion of the script, but wasn't coming up with anything. Is this possible to do?

*Please note that this HTA is for use in Windows PE so while I can utilize VB and, as it seems, some JS, there aren't all the packages for using other languages or updated versions like HTML5, etc...* *

**Update!**

By putting the original VB code [first code sequence shown above] in a separate .vbs document, the code runs perfectly and returns the machine name. I was able to call the .vbs from the .hta, but I'm curious as to what it is that makes the code work in a .vbs file, but not in a .hta.

So the machine name comes up in a pop-up window, and that's now working. From here, I want to make the machine name appear in the HTML input box in my .hta, like I originally intended, rather than the pop-up as is now.

Comment: The fact a HTA is running on Windows PE is irrelevant, IE's CSS support will still be there, although if you're using VBScript IE will have to run in IE7 emulation mode which disables newer features.

Comment: This application is not running in IE, it's a standalone running pre OS. IE is not involved. Not sure if that matters at this point, either.

Comment: If it's running as a HTA then it's running inside an instance of IE running within the HTA host process.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wire-up your code to DOM events. You'll want to change `SN2` into a `Function` (instead of a `Sub`) which returns the computer name, and then call it in the `window.load` event (or do it all inline)

VBScript has no inherent or intrinsic notion of events (technically neither does Javascript), so the platform designers decided to use a "magic" naming convention to handle events, it's clunky. It uses underscores in names to bind functions/subs to DOM object events, the same way how VB6 worked by binding `Button1_Click` to the `Click` event of `Button1`.

There are other ways of binding event-handlers in IE VBScript, none of them pretty. This is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533023(v=vs.85).aspx

Anyway, you'll want this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
Sub Window_onload
    Dim computerNameStr, wmiService, biosRows, biosRow, serialNumber
    computerNameStr = "."

    Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & computerNameStr & "\root\cimv2")
    Set biosRows = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS")
    For Each biosRow in biosRows

        serialNumber = biosRow.SerialNumber
        If Len( serialNumber ) > 0 Then
            window.computerName.value = serialNumber
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="computerName" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JessLovejoy You don't need to call `Window_onload` yourself, instead it uses VBScript's automatic event wiring feature, which is documented in the link I posted. You can disregard my comment about changing `SN2` to a function as my example obviates that suggestion.

Comment: Ok, I'll read up on that link, and I have to test this out on the system to make sure it works :)

Comment: @JessLovejoy you can use a virtual-machine to reduce the test effort required. I personally recommend Oracle VirtualPC - though Hyper-V also works.

Comment: I have a test machine already, it's a preboot environment, so no IE involved at all. Thank you, though. So I was able to test this as suggested and it did not work. This probably has nothing to do with it, but does the fact that I have <body onload="PreloadOptions";> pose a problem with the Sub Window_onload ?

Comment: @Jess yes, having an existing event handle `onload` would cause problems. Move the call to `PreloadOptions` to within the `Window_onload` sub code.

Comment: As in call PreloadOptions within the Window_onload sub? And set <body onload=Window_onload> ? I had tried a few variations of this but nothing comes up in the input. I can't see how to tell if the issue is if the code is not grabbing the computer name, or if it has it, but is not printing it to the input box.

Comment: @Jess As a matter of *practicality*, is there any way you could have the project use Javascript instead of VBScript? It would certainly help to eliminate many of these headaches. Javascript supports all of VBScript's language features though the syntax might be a bit fiddly (e.g. using `for` with an `enumerator` instead of VBScript's `For Each` statement), and `ActiveXObject` instead of VBScript's `CreateObject` / `GetObject`.

Comment: Unfortunately, java is not installed preboot on these machines. So it seems I have to stick to VBScript. It also seems there is something within the PreloadOption sub that gives a "Type Mismatch" error, so I will have to look into that.

Comment: @Jess Javascript has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Ok. Well JS isn't working anyway. Thanks for your help.